# Error: Could not find or load main class Main in CMD

Tags: java, maven, jar, build

I built my maven-project in jar-file with idea. it created manifest.mf where was classpath
but when i run it in cmd i become this error.

this is my pom.xml

```
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <index>true</index>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>E:\IT\GitHub\Clocks\src\main\java\Main.java</mainClass>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathLayoutType>simple</classpathLayoutType>
                        </manifest>
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <mode>development</mode>
                            <url>${project.url}</url>
                            <key>value</key>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

then i tried to add to classpth my Main.java to manifest,
  but it didn't help.

Answer (score 2):

Change `E:\IT\GitHub\Clocks\src\main\java\Main.java` to `Main`

Comment: i did but it doesn't help

Comment: @DanilKuliga than give us more info. Do you clean install your project?